# Angular 2 - Download File form Rest API (CSV)

Tags: angular

I´m trying to download a file from a API . When I `onclick` button launch this function.

```
download(form:any){
        this.fileCtrl.download().subscribe(
          (response:any) => {
            const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'text/csv' });
            console.log(blob);
            const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(url);  
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        )}
    }
```

The function return this error.  Load the image because is "complex" error.

[image: Error]

**UPDATE**

```
  download() {
    return this.http.get(
      "URL",
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          Authorization: "Token " + localStorage.getItem("token")
        })
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Show `this.fileCtrl.download()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Http call should have header `{ responseType: 'blob' }`:

Try like this:

```
this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
```

Once you get the byteArray, use [File-Saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) to download the file.

`import saveAs from 'file-saver';`

```
 this.fileCtrl.download().subscribe(
      (response:any) => {
         saveAs(resp, `file.csv`)
 });
```

Comment: This return in console.log Blob {size: 34064, type: "text/csv"}

Comment: As expected. I am adding the further steps

Comment: As you have accepted the answer, would you mind upvoting it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using third party library you can do following.

1. Get Content-type from the response headers
2. Get Content-disposition headers
3. Get the Content-Diposition attachment
4. Set the file name
5. Create `<a>` tag and set downlaod attribute
6. Create click event on the `<a>`
7. Dispatch the click event.

   `this.http.get(apiURL).subscribe(res =>{`

   `// support Chrome`

   ```
     const isChrome =
       /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) &&
       /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);

     // support firefox
     const isFirefox =
       navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;

     // support IE
     const isIe =
       !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/g) ||
       !!navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/g);

     // get the content-type from the response headers
     let contentType = null;
     contentType = res.headers.get('Content-Type');

     // get content-disposition headers
     const contentDispositionHeader = res.headers.get('Content-Disposition');

     // get the Content-Diposition attachment; filename='x.csv'
     const result = contentDispositionHeader
       .split(';')[1]
       .trim()
       .split('=')[1];

     // get the file name
     const fileName = result.replace(/'/g, '');

     // check if the response and attachment exists, and create anchor tag

     if (res && /attachment/.test(contentDispositionHeader)) {
       // for chrome and firefox
       if (isChrome || isFirefox) {
         const linkElement = document.createElement('a');
         const blob = new Blob([res['_body']], { type: contentType });
         const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
         linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
         linkElement.setAttribute('download', fileName);

         // create a click event on the anchor tag
         const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
           view: window,
           bubbles: true,
           cancelable: false
         });

         // dispatch the click event
         linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
       } else {
         // for IE
         if (isIe) {
           let blob3;
           blob3 = new Blob([res['_body']]);
           if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
             window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob3, fileName);
           }
         }
       }
     }
   })
   ```

Comment: In Angular, it is absolutely fine to use third party libraries. Why reinvent the wheel! :)

Comment: I'm the coder and I don't want to use third party libraries. Also it may create dependency issues, version issues in future. :)

Comment: @AdritaSharma, And also we don't know internally what they're doing in the third party libraries, there may be some security breaches or they may be collecting your data etc.